# Bootstrap: Set navbar to partially overlapp carousel & set to 100% width on resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, navbar

I basically want this [welearn2fly.com](http://welearn2fly.com/law/1/) where half the navbar will overlap my carousel & when mobile screen size is reached I want it to become 100% width. I've had a go but cant get it to overlap or stay under each other whilst being responsive.

Any help? Thanks

Currently this is my code:
CSS & HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/ryqvybde/

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="images/logo1.png" alt="lolalogo" class="image-responsive">
    </div>
    <!-- End logo -->
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- End Header -->
  <!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="Chania">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="Chania">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="Flower">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your CSS as well?

Comment: best put codes in jsfiddle/codepen

Comment: Not sure if I did it right but I added css & jsfiddle